# Get Distinct using LINQ to Objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

My data looks like the following image[image]

So i loaded it into a collection, using anon objects to bypass creating a class

```
List<dynamic> myList = new List<dynamic>()
        {
            new {
                WorkOrderID = 40001,
                LastUpdatedAt = DateTime.Parse("2018-10-02"),
                Col3 = "abc",
                Col4 = "xyz"
            },
            new {
                WorkOrderID = 40001,
                LastUpdatedAt = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-01"),
                Col3 = "abc",
                Col4 = "xyz"
            },
            new {
                WorkOrderID = 40002,
                LastUpdatedAt = DateTime.Parse("2018-07-01"),
                Col3 = "abc",
                Col4 = "xyz"
            },
            new {
                WorkOrderID = 40003,
                LastUpdatedAt = DateTime.Parse("2018-09-01"),
                Col3 = "abc",
                Col4 = "xyz"
            },
            new {
                WorkOrderID = 40001,
                LastUpdatedAt = DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01"),
                Col3 = "abc",
                Col4 = "xyz"
            },
            new {
                WorkOrderID = 40002,
                LastUpdatedAt = DateTime.Parse("2016-12-01"),
                Col3 = "abc",
                Col4 = "xyz"
            },
        };
```

How do I use Linq-to-Objects to extract only DISTINCT WorkOrders that were updated most recently.

In other words, i should end up with the 3 rows highlighted in Orange.

> var myFilteredList = myList.GroupBy( //?? Totally lost... help...

Comment: It would be awesome if you could be explicit about the results you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding, you want the newest item per work order.

```
var latestWorkOrders = myList
    .GroupBy(w => w.WorkOrderID)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(w => w.LastUpdatedAt).First());
```

It will group by the `WorkOrderID`, and for each grouping select the newest item.

Comment: is your left hand side latestWorkOrders a LINQ query, rather than final result? i.e. i still need to do var finalList = latestWorkOrders.ToList()

Comment: Sorry, yes. It's a LINQ query, so you will need `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 2):

The following uses the `GroupBy` overload so the element selection can be done in the same call and convert them to strongly typed anonymous object.

```
var myFilteredList = myList
    .GroupBy(_ => (int)_.WorkOrderID, (k, g) =>
    {
        var recent = g.OrderByDescending(_ => _.LastUpdatedAt).First();
        return new
        {
            WorkOrderID = k,
            LastUpdatedAt = (DateTime)recent.LastUpdatedAt,
            Col3 = (string)recent.Col3,
            Col4 = (string)recent.Col4
        };
    });
```

**[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ABZ7Y7)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It does work but i went with the first correct reply; Your left hand side is a linq query, rather than the final list, missing a .ToList() cast at the end ?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<dynamic> list = myList
               .GroupBy(a => a.WorkOrderID )
               .OrderByDescending(b => b.LastUpdatedAt)
               .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
               .ToList();

foreach (var p in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.WorkOrderID + " : " + p.Col3);
}
```

Personally, dynamic isnt a good choice. If you have an object, then you can implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on the Object. This way you can do:

```
var list = myList.Select(o => new { o.WorkOrderID, ... })
                                       .Distinct();
```

which is much cleaner.

Comment: IGrouping<dynamic, dynamic> does not contain a definition for LastUpdatedAt.